# Defining inner section on HTML5 markup

Tags: html, semantic-markup

A question about HTML5 markup. Which is correct?

```html
<header class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
    </div>
</header>
```

-OR-

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="wrapper-inner">
    </header>
</div>
```

---

```css
.wrapper { width: 100%; }
.wrapper-inner { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaving attributes (like `lang`) aside, you can ignore `div` and `span` elements, as they are meaningless. So (apart from the different classes) your examples are semantically equivalent.

Assuming that the `.wrapper` element won’t contain anything else than the `.wrapper-inner` element, it’s up to you which one to use for which.

A possible benefit of using `<header><div></div></header>` over `<div><header></header></div>` could be that it might be easier for markup authors to spot the `header` in the document, as authors wouldn’t have to "enter" the `div` element to check what it contains and what it’s used for.

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct.

If you want to use  as a sectioning element for the page, then, you likely want:

```
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-subsection">
    </div>
</header>
```

If you want to use  as a sectioning element for a sub-section of the page, then, you likely want:

```
<section class="author-biography">
    <header class="author-name-and-thumbnail">
    </header>
</section>
```