# Wrapper inside or outside HTML5 semantics main, which is best practice?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

Does anyone know which of these is best practice?

- A: Layout wrapper inside `main`
- B: Layout wrapper outside `main`

I know it is bad practice to style HTML5 semantics hence why I have styled a `div` element for wrapping the layout for the page content, but I am unsure what the best practice is regarding where to place the wrapper in regards to HTML5 semantics `main` or if it even matters.

SEO is my main concern more than anything.

The wrapper is for content only, the `footer` and `header` are outside the wrapper.

CSS:

```css
#wrapper {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 1200px;
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto;
   padding: 100px 0 200px 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML A:

```html
<main role="main">
   <div id=wrapper></div>
</main>
```

HTML B:

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <main role="main"></main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it is bad practice to style HTML5 semantics hence why I have styled a `div` element for wrapping the layout for the page content […]

It is **not** a bad practice to style HTML5 elements like `main`. I would call it a bad practice to add `div` elements if you don’t really need them.

You should not add meaningful elements (i.e., everything except [`div` and `span`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868474/1591669)) just because you need an element for styling reasons, but if you need an element because of its semantics, there’s nothing wrong with styling it.

If you do need a wrapping `div`: semantically it [makes no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33802881/1591669) if it’s inside or outside.

Comment: In my situation it is very bad practice, it is an extremely high traffic website and amongst my users atleast 4% are using IE6-8 with no Javascript. This makes up a good 25,000 page views a day on average.

HTML5 semantics do not degrade gracefully without Javascript so by styling the semantics it breaks the whole layout for browsers that do not support HTML5 semantics, leaving the styling to divs gives a graceful fallback.

I just want to know if it makes any difference to SEO and the way search engines read your website if my styling div is inside or outside the semantic.

Comment: @Ash: Wow, that’s really a high proportion of IE 6/7/8 users that don’t have JS enabled. So in your case it can make sense to add a `div` for each "new" block-level HTML5 element. As stated, semantically it makes no difference (therefore there’s no reason to assume that it would matter for SEO).

Comment: Ah ok, thankyou.
I think I get a lot of the London lunchtime break, and a lot of banks / hedgefunds force Internet Explorer 6 with no Javascript on their employees to be backwards compatible with old bespoke systems.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use "B" because when you set the ID to wrapper it's read more easily by Bootstrap (in case you are using it). The other thing you should keep in mind is the child parent relation and to be careful not to override it. I hope my answer helps.