# Is the <header> tag purely semantic or can i use it like a <div> tag and style it?

Tags: html, header, markup

Since HTML5 introduced some new tags such as header, footer, aside, nav, etc. I wanted to know if it was good practice to use those tags like they were a div tag?

Let me explain:

I want to have a fixed menu on my website that stays fixed on the top as the user scrolls down the page, so I created a header tag and then i used CSS and gave it a position: fixed; and gave it some other rules...

^Is this recommended? (Giving the header tag some styles)
Or is the header tag only used for markup purposes?

Should I create a div tag inside the header tag and style that div tag? Or is it fine to just style the header tag?

```
<header>

</header>
```

OR

```
<header>
 <div id="header>

 </div>
</header>
```

This question also applies to the footer tag and those new HTML5 tags that are used for markup.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34527913/1591669) could be a duplicate (not the same question, but the answer would be the same).

Answer (score 0):

A  header tag typically contains heading tag(Not restricted). You can also use the elements like table of contents, logos etc.

You can also style the header

But in legacy browser like (IE <9) to render the  element as a block level element you will need to explicitly declare it as a block in your CSS like so: header { display:block;}

I don't think there is any need of  tag.

Answer (score 0):

The header tag can be styled directly as same as styling div tags. just give id/class for the header as you give id/class to the div tags.

If you are planning to do a fixed nav bar at the top i would suggest for using nav tags instead of header.

Correct me if i am wrong